# Rails simple_form element with data-... attributes for stimulus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, stimulusjs

I am trying to hook up a stimulus controller to a form element which is inside a form generated by the simple form gem. Whatever I do - the corresponding "data-controller" attribute doesn't appear in the final rendered page (and hence, the controller won't react)...

Here's the code in question:

```
<%= simple_form_for book do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/form_errors', form: f %>
  ...
  <%= f.association :book_format, label: false, 'data-controller': 'book-format-select' %>
  ...
< % end %>
```

I also tried

```
<%= f.association :book_format, label: false, data_controller: 'book-format-select' %>
```

and

```
<%= f.association :book_format, label: false, html: {data-controller: 'book-format-select' } %>
```

None of that works - the output is always the same:

```
<select class="select required" name="book[book_format_id]" id="book_book_format_id">
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`input_html`](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#usage) key

> It is also possible to pass any html attribute straight to the input, by using the `:input_html` option

```
<%= f.association :book_format, label: false, input_html: { data: { controller: 'book-format-select' } } %>
```